# How to show that $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the norm $\|\cdot \| = \|\cdot \|_1+\|\cdot \|_2$ is uniformly convex

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

$\|\cdot \| = \|\cdot \|_1+\|\cdot \|_2$ is clearly a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I need to show that $\mathbb{R}^2$ with this norm is uniformly convex.

There are various definitions of uniform convexity, but I cannot find a way to use the most appropriate definition and obtain the desired result.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Well, shall we start with the definition that $\mathbb R^2$ is uniformly convex iff for every $0<\varepsilon\leqslant 2$ there exists $\delta>0$ so that for any two unit vectors $x$ and $y$, $\|x-y\|\geqslant\varepsilon$ implies that $\left\|\frac{x+y}2\right\|\leqslant 1-\delta$?

Comment: Hint: uniform convexity is a geometric property of the norm; an equivalent norm is not necessarily uniformly convex. So there is something special about this norm you must use.

Comment: Actually I am reading that $\mathbb R^2$ with the $\ell^1$ norm is *not* uniformly convex. Are you convinced the statement should be true?

Comment: Yes this must be true. I think the $l^2$ norm works in a special way....